# IOS swift bring selected cell to top

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

How to resort `tableViewCell` so when I click on any cell it will move to the top|beginning of the cell

Example cell

```
Java
PHP
CSS /clicked on/
HTML
SQL
```

Expected result

```
CSS
Java
PHP
HTML
SQL
```

Comment: Please share your attempted code.

Comment: Here's a hint to the solution, You can add a sortOrder in your array, and reload the tableView after updating sortOrder for the selected cell.

Comment: @UmairAfzal I don't have any attempt because I don't have idea on where to start and I searched but couldn't see any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var languages = [
        "CSS",
        "Java",
        "PHP",
        "HTML",
        "SQL"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return languages.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = languages[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        languages.insert(languages.remove(at: indexPath.row), at: 0)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: [0, 0])
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

[image: Table reordering on tap]

Comment: As always `begin-/endUpdates` is pointless for a **single** insert/delete/move operation